# Massive number of XML edits

Tags: haskell

I need to load a mid-sized XML file into memory, make many random access modifications to the file (perhaps hundreds of thousands), then write the result out to STDIO.  Most of these modifications will be node insertion/deletions, as well as character insertion/deletions within the text nodes.  These XML files will be small enough to fit into memory, but large enough that I won't want to keep multiple copies around.

I am trying to settle on the architecture/libraries and am looking for suggestions.

Here is what I have come up with so far-

I am looking for the ideal XML library for this, and so far, I haven't found anything that seems to fit the bill.  The libraries generally store nodes in Haskell lists, and text in Haskell Data.Text objects.  This only allows linear Node and Text inserts, and I believe that the Text inserts will have to do full rewrite on every insert/delete.

I think storing both nodes and text in sequences seems to be the way to go....  It supports log(N) inserts and deletes, and only needs to rewrite a small fraction of the tree on each alteration.  None of the XML libs are based on this though, so I will have to either write my own lib, or just use one of the other libs to parse then convert it to my own form (given how easy it is to parse XML, I would almost just as soon do the former, rather than have a shadow parse of everything).

I had briefly considered the possibility that this might be a rare case where Haskell might not be the best tool....  But then I realized that mutability doesn't offer much of an advantage here, because my modifications aren't char replacements, but rather add/deletes.  If I wrote this in C, I would still need to store the strings/nodes in some sort of tree structure to avoid large byte moves for each insert/delete.  (Actually, Haskell probably has some of the best tools to deal with this, but I would be open to suggestions of a better choice of language for this task if you feel there is one).

To summarize-

1. Is Haskell the right choice for this?
2. Does any Haskell lib support fast node/text insert/deletes (log(N))?
3. Is sequence the best data structure to store a list of items (in my case, Nodes and Chars) for fast insert and deletes?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question-

I chose to wrap an Text.XML tree with a custom object that stores nodes and text in Data.Sequence objects.  Because haskell is lazy, I believe it only temporarily holds the Text.XML data in memory, node by node as the data streams in, then it is garbage collected before I actually start any real work modifying the Sequence trees.

(It would be nice if someone here could verify that this is how Haskell would work internally, but I've implemented things, and the performance seems to be reasonable, not great- about 30k insert/deletes per second, but this should do).